# How to read JSON that starts with square brackets using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to read a JSON list of elements using Jackson library?
It basically starts with square brackets, like the following one :

```
[
   {
      "firstName":"a",
      "lastName":"a"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"b",
      "lastName":"b"
   },
   {
      "firstName":"c",
      "lastName":"c"
   }
]
```

Most of the time the JSON starts with curly brackets and it is easy to map it to a java class :

```
Person person = mapper.readValue(fileReader, Person.class);
```

But when the JSON starts with Square brackets how it can be read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two solution:

If you want to load everything immediately:

```
List<Person> people = mapper.readValue(fileReader, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, Person.class));
```

or faster

```
List<Person> people = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(fileReader, Person[].class))
```

otherwise you can retrieve a MappingIterator to iterate over the elements

```
MappingIterator<Person> iterator = mapper.readerFor(Person.class).readValues(fileReader);
```

If you choose the version with MappingIterator, please remember to close the iterator when you have finish to use it, in order to release any resources associated with it.